# Cassandra - Failed to start LSB

Tags: cassandra, centos7, cassandra-3.0

My problem is the error message below when I try to start my Cassandra service on CentOS7.

```
  Failed to start LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
```

My Cassandra server was working properly. But, I had to reboot the Cassandra machine (my Cassandra is running on a single machine only). 
I tried to connect to cqlsh and I faced with message refusion connection. Therefore, I tried to restart Cassandra. I received: Job for cassandra.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status cassandra.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
When I ran journalctl -xe, I received my error message.

Please, let me know suggestions for fixing this error.

I appreciate any help.

Best regards,

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/836059/sudo-service-status-includes-bad